# Is there a specific name for $\omega$?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for this ordinal $\omega$, just like its cardinal $\aleph_0$ has a name "aleph null set"?

Whenever I do my assignment about cardinality of sets (not in set theory class), if I want to make my proof precise, I introduce $\omega$ as "the least infinite ordinal" or "the least limit ordinal". I wonder if there is a fancy word like "aleph-null set".

Comment: It's mostly called "omega" in my experience. If you're talking about ordinals, and you say "omega", then I am [almost certain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) there won't be any confusion.

Comment: @Arthur If there is a confusion, then is there any other name substitute to omega?

Comment: @Arthur If it is my own work, it's fine. However, i'm asking this since there are *few* professors don't care about *precise arguments about cardinality* but hand out assignments proving some statements about cardinality.

Comment: In that case you start by saying "Let $\omega$ be the first infinite ordinal", and from then on you can continue without worry.

Comment: How about omega-naught? (Since sometimes $\omega_0$ is used to denote $\omega$.)